# How to set my result in the spring context which i fetched from database?

Tags: spring

I fetch the same data from the database but i want to store it the spring context how it is possible?

I have a scenario in which i hit to the database and fetch the same result each time, so how i add my object in spring context and fetch this from context each time?

Comment: Take a look at Caching. Spring provides support for caching: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use spring cache api. First time when you call Cacheable method spring checks that there is nothing in cache and execute load method (and put result into cache), second time spring checks that there is result for method call and returns resalt from cache do not executed the method.

Here is example  [example from  spring web site](http://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/)  and [better example](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial)
 And [api](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/EnableCaching.html)

```
@Component
public class SimpleBookRepository implements BookRepository {

@Override
@Cacheable("books")
public Book getByIsbn(String isbn) {
    simulateSlowService();
    return new Book(isbn, "Some book");
}

// Don't do this at home
private void simulateSlowService() {
    try {
        long time = 3000L;
        Thread.sleep(time);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

}

---

based on your code :

```
@Component
public class MasterDataLoader implements InitializingBean {
    private Set<String> country = new HashSet<String>();

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        country = getknowledgebase();
    }

    @Cacheable("country")
    public Set<String> getknowledgebase() {
        Connection con = null;
        Set<String> country =new HashSet<>();
        try {
            con = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM knowledgebase");
            while (rs.next()) {
                if (rs.getString("country") != null) {
                    country.add(rs.getString("country").toLowerCase());
                }
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return country;
    }
}
```

-- constructor it's not the best place where you should do some logic , better move logic into some private method , and call one from constuctor.

- also , probably you don't need spring cache for this, I think set is enough. just return Set coutries from method get.... and that method returns counties.

---

Update 2 : 
for case when you can all data and they don't change in db in time

```
@Component
public class MasterDataLoader implements InitializingBean {
    private Set<String> country = new HashSet<String>();
    private Set<String> streets = new HashSet<String>();
    private Set<String> state = new HashSet<String>();

    public Set<String> getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public Set<String> getStreets() {
        return streets;
    }

    public Set<String> getState() {
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        loadCachedData();
    }


    private void  loadCachedData() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM knowledgebase");
            while (rs.next()) {
                if (rs.getString("country") != null) {
                    country.add(rs.getString("country").toLowerCase());
                    streets.add(rs.getString("street").toLowerCase());
                    state.add(rs.getString("state").toLowerCase());
                }
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and  if data might change

```
@Cacheable("country")
public Set<String> getCountry() {
    return method that load country from DB;
}

@Cacheable("street")
public Set<String> getStreets() {
    return method that load street from DB;
}

@Cacheable("state")
public Set<String> getState() {
    return method that load state from DB;
}
```

Comment: Can we not do this by creating a bean and put my logic into constructor and we know that bean created by ioc container is default put into application context?

Comment: @Component
public class MasterDataLoader{
 Set<String> country=new HashSet<String>(); getter,setter
 public MasterDataLoader() {
      Connection con=null;
      try{
       con= ConnectionProvider.getConnection();
          Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM knowledgebase");
          while(rs.next()){
           //Retrieve by column name
           if(rs.getString("country")!=null)
           country.add(rs.getString("country").toLowerCase());
            }rs.close();
      }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}}

Comment: ioc container created my bean and put this object in application context by default. am i right?

Comment: @Cacheable how it work in my case? How this cache works?

Comment: when you call first time method with @@Cacheable getknowledgebase it's do real call do db , second time call getknowledgebase  doesn't call db and return values from cache

Comment: But i have more than one field like country,state,street, which i set from the method which return void  so how could i make all these cacheable like you make @Cacheable("country") plz suggest.

Comment: see Update 2. you don't need spring cache in your case.spring cache use when you call spring method that might return data that are changed.

Comment: Thanks for you Great Support